SAML - identity providers accepting simple url requests
trying to set a SAML login flow into my web app (in this case, react on rails, but it's not really relevant to the problem).
i got a flow working where the service provider sends a saml request, it's being authenticated by the idp, sending the authenticared mail back to the sdp, and then this mail is being checked in the app's user database. this part is working fine.
however, i noticed that when i take the idp's sso url, and** just paste it to the url bar **in chrome, it still goes to the idp and let's me authenticate.
is there some key configuration i'm missing? i've tried okta and onelogin.
maybe i'm missing something, but it doesn't make sense to me that the idps even start the authentication flow without any saml attached to the request.
on my app there are some measures of security ofcourse, using a certificate and a sp_entity_id which are being checked when there's a request coming in from the idp.
but it's confusing me that there the idp "doesn't care" if there is a saml coming in before starting to authenticate.
can't really share screenshots from the configurations.
is there a key configuration i should look into?
the main idp i'm intending to use is onelogin.

The request that goes from SP to IDP is just a simple redirect. Anyone can use it. But once the user is authenticated, the response always goes to the SP's pre-defined URL i.e. ACS URL. So you don't have to worry about the link being reused.
If IDP's session is there already, then IDP will redirect the user to the SP home page(of course if authentication is successful).
